# How can I configure F# inspections in Jetbrains Rider?

Tags: f#, rider

I have an F# project that compiles in VS and in Jetbrains Rider.
However, the inspection tool displays errors, for instance for the code:

```
type DU =
    | A of int

function
| A -> ()  // <- jetbrains inspection complains but Jetbrains compiler compiles - so they are out of sync
```

Some (I guess the later) F# compiler versions complain with FS0019, my VS version and latest Jetbrains Rider compile this code however, VS does not even warn.

My question is not about the code example above but only:

**How can I configure the F# inspection?**

Or similar:
Which tool does the inspection?
How can I get inspection and compilation into sync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetbrains notified me that configuration of f# inspection severity is in progress. Its possible to push the urgency here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-28183

open remains the question why the code compiles while inspection calls out error.

the code itself was valid only for some versions of f#, that was changed later. so i guess part of the configuration of inspection severity should be which compiler version to use for inspection - VS Code for instance has exactly this feature: for each typescript file one can set the version of the typescript compiler that is used for syntax highlighting and so on.